# Register null as instance in Unity container

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I have a repository class with optional dependency:

```
class MyRepository : BaseRepository, IMyRepository
{
    public MyRepository(IDataContext dataContext, ICacheProvider cacheProvider = null)
        : base(dataContext, cacheProvider)
    {}

    // …
}
```

The existence of cacheProvider parameter acts as strategy for the repository.
I want setup Unity container like this:

```
Container.RegisterType<IDataContext, MyDataContext>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor())
         .RegisterInstance<ICacheProvider>(null) // ???
         .RegisterType<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
```

I.e. not pointing out particular InjectionConstructor with one parameter for MyRepository, but use default constructor with null as *cacheProvider* parameter.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why have an *optional* dependency? Just implement an `ICacheProvider` that does nothing.

Comment: @dtryon, yes. The only option that came to my mind is to create NullObject implementation of the ICacheProvider.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the `.RegisterType<IMyRepository, MyRepository>()` call, specify the [InjectionConstructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.injectionconstructor%28PandP.20%29.aspx) with an [OptionalParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.optionalparameter%28PandP.20%29.aspx), as in

```
.RegisterType<IMyRepository, MyRepository>(new InjectionConstructor(
new ResolvedParameter<IDataContext>(), 
new OptionalParameter<ICacheProvider>()));
```

Comment: Looks like what's i'm asking for. Have not enough time right now to check out if this solution plays nice with `PerResolveLifetimeManager`, but i believe it does.

Comment: IMO it is really bad that Unity even contains a `OptionalParameter` class that allows you to inject `null` values into constructors. This is really bad application design and the framework should prevent users from doing this.

Comment: FYI, order matters when defining the parameters here.

Answer (score 28):

I found that RegisterType, instead of Register instance, supports returning null.

```
container.RegisterType<IInterface>(new InjectionFactory((c) => null));
```

This was the most straightforward way of getting an actual `null` to be returned.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I got `Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type RazorEngineService does not have an accessible constructor.` when I configured `IRazorEngineService` to return null. Not sure why yet; I hadn't mentioned the concrete..

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks!

Comment: Nice. Easy but this is obsolete now.

Answer (score 6):

For *'nice to have'* dependencies you should use property injection instead of ctor injection. Config would look something like this:

```
public class MyRepository
{
  public ICacheProvider Cache { get; set; }
}

container.RegisterType<MyRepository>(new InjectionProperty("Cache", typeof(ICacheProvider)));
```

That would inject an implementation of `ICacheProvider` into a property named `Cache` of your `MyRepository`. As you would have to implement null checks wherever you make a call to the `Cache` property inside your repository class I would go with @dtryon's proposal and implement a `NullCacheProvider`. That is far more convenient and less error prone.

Answer (score 4):

**Simplest Non-Obsolete solution**

Calling RegisterType with an InjectionFactory is currently obsolete, so here is the currently recommended approach:

```
container.RegisterFactory<ITypeToResolve>(c => null);
```

---

**Flexible Extension Method**

Or if you want to make an extension method to return anything you want you could do something like:

```
public static void RegisterFactory<TToResolve>(IUnityContainer container, Func<TToResolve> factory) => 
        container.RegisterFactory<TToResolve>(c => factory.Invoke());
```

Then to consume that you'd do:

```
container.RegisterFactory<ITypeToResolve>(() => new MyTypeToResolve());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ended with implementing some sort of a NullObject pattern on my optional dependency:

```
public class NullCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
    // …
}
```

And in the base repository class i have check:

```
public class BaseRepository
{
    protected readonly ICacheProvider CacheProvider;
    protected readonly bool ShouldUseCache;

    protected BaseRepository(IDataContext context, ICacheProvider cacheProvider)
    {
        CacheProvider = cacheProvider;
        ShouldUseCache = 
            CacheProvider != null && !(CacheProvider is NullCacheProvider);
    }
}
```

Then in a projects where i don't need a cache i have configured Unity like this:

```
container
    .RegisterType<IDataContext, MyDataContext>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor())
    .RegisterType<ICacheProvider, NullCacheProvider>() 
    .RegisterType<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
```

The point of all this is that the particular repository may act differently depending on fact of existence the optional dependency. It may seem as some architectural flaw but the solution meets my requirements.

Comment: If you used the Null Object Pattern, you should mark Sabastian as answer, not cynic. Also note that it is better to merge this answer with your question.

Comment: In your final implementation, your `BaseRepository` now depends on the `ICacheProvider` implementation `NullCacheProvider` which is a bad thing. There is no need for the `BaseRepository` to know anything about implementations, that's the idea behind the Null Object pattern. Instead, prevent callers from injecting `null` in the `cacheProvider` parameter. When you implemented this default cache provider correctly, you don't need the `ShouldUseCache`, which makes the code simpler and more maintainable.

Comment: @Steven, in general i would agree with you. But in the case the `Repository` must know whether it has `ICacheProvider` or not, and with this knowledge modify own behavior (change fetch plan and use cache to load entities). So it is not canonical implementation of the Null Object pattern, but only workaround as i had no better ideas.

Comment: Implementing the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) does not mean that this implementation does nothing, but that it implements "neutral behavior". In your case the neutral behavior would be an implementation that allows your `Repository` to work without having to worry about whether entities are cached or not. Take a step back and look at your design.